# Effects of heat on Black body

Tags: thermodynamics

Why a perfectly black body appears white when it is heated to high temperature?
Specify with reason, please.

Answer (score 2):

The phenomenon is called [Black body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation).

As a black body is heated it starts emitting electromagnetic radiation. Below is the *spectrum* of this radiation in function of the body's temperature:

[image: Black body radiation]

For clarity the spectrum of visible light has been added (the 'colours of the rainbow'). Observe as for each temperature the *peak* power output (light intensity) is shown and how that peak shifts further and further towards the visible light spectrum with increasing temperature.

At relatively low temperature, say $800\:\mathrm{Celsius}$ or so, most of the emitted radiation lies in the Infra Red and red parts of the spectrum and a body at that temperature will glow a dull red.

As temperature increases, the body emits a greater and greater portion of its radiation in the visible part of the spectrum. The colour of the object thus gradually changes from red, to orange, to yellow, to white, as temperature gradually increases.

Very hot objects thus glow yellow/white, as for instance does our Sun.

Comment: The sun is actually white hot when seen from space, but our atmosphere impose scattering so that it appears yellowish or bluish

Answer (score 0):

At high temperatures the spectrum of the blackbody exhibit an emission spectrum that has a mixture of light frequency intensities for the eye that produces a white light impression. The same occurs when iron or coal is glowing at high temperature. According to Planck's law, these light intensities for different frequencies are, of course, not constant as ideal white light would require.

Answer (score 0):

A black body is an ideal hypothetical body that absorbs all incident electromagnetic radiation, regardless of frequency or angle of incidence. A black body in thermal equilibrium emits electromagnetic radiation called black-body radiation.

The color of a black body depends on the temperature of the cavity. When heated, depending upon the temperature of the cavity, the wavelength of radiation emitted by the black body changes. At high temperatures, the the black body emits radiations of all wavelengths and hence the body appears as white, because white is the color that we perceive when something emits all colors. When called, the black body absorbs all radiation and hence appears black.

So, at high temperatures the black body appears to be white (white hot) and at very low temperatures, it appears black. An example is a tungsten filament. It can be considered as an approximation to a black body. When current passes through it, the temperature rises and the color changes from red, blue and finally white.